# cant create a SelectedIndexChanged event for dropdownlist in gridview FooterTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a dropdownlist for the products description in the footer template.
There is no way to create a SelectedIndexChanged in the IDE and writing it out manually produces an error? How to create code to handle the Selection change? I need to populate the product ids when the product description is selected.

"EDITED"
I tried using the gridview rowediting event assuming that if a row item was changed (ie, a new selection in the dropdown, it would fire, but it doesn't) It appears a gridview event has to be fired when that dropdown list changes, that's where i need the code to go. Any ides on what event?

Here is what the template field markup is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description">

            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductDesc" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsProductDesc" DataTextField="description"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProductDesc_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="tbInsertdescriptiton" Width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProdDesc"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: there is no view at all of the dropdownlist events because its buried in a gridview footer template. I have to cast those controls, but from what gridview event?

Comment: have you set autopostback=true

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7228/asp-net-gridview-dropdown-with-related-records-in-textbox.aspx